# Assembly language, don't understand the instruction codes and memory locations

Tags: assembly, digital-logic, 68hc12

I'm studying for a test in my digital design class and I don't understand some things.  Here is the worksheet with the answers on it,[image]

1. I understand the PC address for each instruction.  What I don't understand is on b, where it says where does the branch jump to, which instruction does the 68hc12 fetch and execute after the branch.  I see 080B 20 F8, but what does that mean exactly,  like 080B is the slot in memory where the instruction is held but what does the 20 F8 after mean?  also I don't quite understand A in part C, any help would be awesome.

Comment: and do you understand the difference between assembly and java?

Comment: yeah I did not mean to put java as a tag I'm trying to remove it haha.

Comment: okay, how does that translate to the instruction jumping to 0805?  Like how did my professor get 080D - F8

Comment: If you are asking questions like these at this point it indicates you have not assimilated some fundamental concepts that should be pretty clear.  You should be talking this over with your professor and/or teaching assistant.  We cannot provide you with all the material you seem to have missed.

Comment: Learned this 1 day before class stopped meeting until the final and I'm not on a schedule where I can meet with my teacher.  I'm just trying to figure out the machine code and opcode part.  Thanks for your passive aggression.

Comment: @C.Sullivan The gold reference for the 68HC12 is [the following document](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/reference-manuals/CPU12RM.pdf). Absorb it and you are safe for the final. The instruction set's detailed documentation is Chapter 6 and a very readable summary that shows exactly the machine-coding of all instructions is in Appendix A.

Comment: thanks man, appreciate it.

Comment: Just to make sure you got it (as I don't see it clearly stated in the nice answer from Peter): In the listing `080B 20 F8` is from two parts. The `080B` is memory address, not part of the memory values, but part of memory chip wiring. `20 F8` are two byte values stored in the memory chip, at address `080B` (`20`) and `080C` (`F8`). When you set `PC` to `080B` (for example by some branch instruction), the CPU will fetch from memory byte `20`, partly-decode that as `bra`, so it will fetch another missing byte `F8` to complete the instruction opcode, finish the decoding, and prepare that for exec

Answer (score 4):

A) explains that `20 F8` is the raw machine code for `bra loop`, and that it's not shown for the other instructions.

Apparently you're supposed to know enough about the machine-code format to figure out where that branches to.

I don't know 68HC12, but from experience with other ISAs (like x86), I assume 0x20 is the opcode and 0xF8 is a signed 2's complement relative displacement, probably relative to the *end* of the branch instruction.

Oh, yes the solution written in for part C confirms that.  But `0x080D + 0xF8` only works if there's no carry from the low byte to high byte.  Unless 68hc12 displacements are weird or there's segmentation, you have to sign extend that *before* adding, so it's `0x080D + 0xFFF8`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  The only thing I think I'm not understanding is why does the program not loop back to 080B-F8?  How do we know that we jump 2 bytes forward and then do 080D-F8.  Does it have to do with the bra instruction being 2 bytes?

Comment: @C. Sullivan This looks strikingly like a homework I did a long time ago. Having programmed the 68HC12, I can confirm the near branch uses an 8-bit signed displacement measured from immediately after the instruction's end. In this case the loop points to the second instruction before the branch.

Comment: Did you happen to go to SIUE?

Comment: bra is `PC = PC + 2 + rel`and it's encoding is `20 rel` with rel in 2-complement. F8=-8, so target address is 80b + 2 - 8 = 805

Comment: @C.Sullivan it's because the branch instruction was already fetched and decoded, so the `PC` is already pointing at next instruction after it (`0x080D`) (preparing to fetch & decode it), then the branch instruction execution kicks in and realizes it want to follow the branch, so the sign-extended -8 is added to current `PC`, not the original one of `bra` instruction. (The CPU itself works in sort of "steps", from ASM programmers point of view you often think about instructions being sort of "instant" or "atomic", but actually their execution can take serious effort and several steps on CPU)